# Utilizar maior precisão Possível no GPS Android

Tags: java, android, gps

Estou construindo uma app que ao passar por uma "linha", definida por um intervalo de latitudes e longitudes, reconhece a passagem e exibe isso em uma `View`.

Porém notei que ao passar pelo intervalo em uma velocidade mais alta, a bordo de um veículo, ele não reconhece a passagem.

Como posso obter essa precisão em uma velocidade maior?

```
package br.com.nobre.ntrack.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import br.com.nobre.ntrack.R;
import br.com.nobre.ntrack.config.Permissoes;

public class NavegacaoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private String[] permissoes = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private TextView txtLat, txtLong, txtVelocidade, txtParcial;

    private Double testeMaior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste_navegacao);

        Permissoes.validarPermissoes(permissoes, this, 1);

        txtLat = findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
        txtLong = findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
        txtVelocidade = findViewById(R.id.txtVelocidade);
        txtParcial = findViewById(R.id.txtParcial);

        Double lat1, lat2;
        lat1 = -29.909756; // maior
        lat2 = -29.909811;


        Log.i("teste", "maior = " + testeMaior);
        txtParcial.setText("Não passou");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("teste de localizacao", "Localizacao: " + location.toString());
                Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                float velocidade = location.getSpeed();

                txtLat.setText("lat: " + latitude);
                txtLong.setText("long: " + longitude);
                double velocidadeEmKm = (velocidade * 3.6);
                txtVelocidade.setText("velocidade: " + velocidadeEmKm);

                //-29.909737, -51.142835
                //-29.909846, -51.142851

                if (latitude >= -29.909846 && latitude <= -29.909737) {
                    if (longitude >= -51.142851 && longitude <= -51.142835) {
                        // esta passando na parcial teste efetuado com sucesso


                        txtParcial.setText("Passou pela parcial");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        // recuperar localização do usuario
        /*
         * 1 - provedor de localização
         * 2 - Tempo mínimo entre atualizações de localização (milesegundos)
         * 3 - Distância mínima entre atualizações de localização (metros)
         * Location Listner ( Para recebermos as atualizações)*/
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for (int permissaoResultado : grantResults) {
            if (permissaoResultado == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                //Alerta
                alertaValidacaoPermissao();
            } else if (permissaoResultado == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // recuperar localização do usuario
                /*
                 * 1 - provedor de localização
                 * 2 - Tempo mínimo entre atualizações de localização (milesegundos)
                 * 3 - Distância mínima entre atualizações de localização (metros)
                 * Location Listner ( Para recebermos as atualizações)*/
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void alertaValidacaoPermissao() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.permissoes_negadas));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.mensagem_permissoes_negadas));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.confirmar_permissoes_negadas), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei quão largo é esse intervalo que você referiu e também não sei de quanto em quanto tempo sua aplicação lê a coordenada. Mas digamos que tenha 100 metros de largura e durante o tempo que você esteve entre as coordenadas o sistema não leu ou se a unica leitura que ele fez caiu fora desse intervalo ele não reconhecerá.

Comment: Quando você esta dirigindo com o Waze e sai para uma via paralela, ele demora um longo tempo até 'perceber' que você saiu da via principal.

Comment: Outro detalhe importante o Waze ( por exemplo ) consegue um nível de acurácia bom porque ele usa outro mapa para corrigir os pontos que recebe do GPS. Se você não fizer nenhuma correção os pontos podem ficar bem espalhados, e é natural isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)
 e defina a prioridade `LocationRequest` como [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

Veja os detalhes sobre precisão nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6775456/6889106)

De modo resumido, a API do Google Play Services tem inteligência para obter uma localização precisa ao fundir GPS_PROVIDER + NETWORK_PROVIDER + PASSIVE_PROVIDER.

Comment: Muito obrigado!